# Create white background with gimpfu

Tags: python, gimp, gimpfu

I want to create a white background in my gimpfu plugin. I found the option to fill a drawable by using `pdb.gimp_drawable_fill(drawable, 2)` but there I have to select a drawable and the drawable fills not automatically the whole image.

Is there an option in gimpfu to fill the whole image with one color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Gimp you have to paint/fill on a layer, so you add a layer that you fill:

```
# Create layer
background=gimp.Layer(image,'Background',image.width,image.height,RGB_IMAGE,100.,LAYER_MODE_NORMAL)
# Fill with white (this doesn't consider the selection, the whole layer is always painted)
background.fill(FILL_WHITE)
# Add at bottom of layer stack
image.add_layer(background,len(image.layers))
```

if you want something else than white, then replace `background.fill(FILL_WHITE)` with

```
import gimpcolor

gimp.set_background(gimpcolor.RGB(100,120,140))
background.fill(FILL_BACKGROUND)
```

Comment: Thats work very fine. Thank you.

Comment: OK, so consider making the answer as accepted so that others can find it